# How to find the second, third and nth maximum row in R with more than 10 variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 20 variables out of which I need to use 10 variables to find the first ,second, 3rd.....nth maximum .

The variables are `x1` to `x10`

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
 1  2  0  3  4  5  6  7  8   5
 2  1  5  4  6  4  2  1  0   3
```

My expected output should be:

```
max1 max2 max3 max4 max5 max6 max7 max8 max9 max10
  x9   x8   x7   x6  x10   x5   x4   x2   x1    x3 
  x5   x3   x4   x6  x10   x1   x7   x2   x8    x9
```

I have 100 observation. The sample I provided is only one row.

Comment: `order(x,decreasing=T)` ?

Comment: when you say that 10 variables are used to find the first, second, ... maximum what do you mean by that ? is it a conditional maximum ?

Comment: for example i have said 10 it can go to 100 variable also that mean 100 maximum also need to display

Comment: could you give us the exact dimension of your dataset : how many rows, columns ? do you want the max of each column, of each row ? do you want to order each rows by decreasing values, each columns, ... ?

Comment: i have 100 row and 10 column. i want max of each row . max1 to max 10

Comment: then try `apply(df,1,max)` : it will return the max of each row (replace 1 by 2 if you want for columns) if your dataset is named `df`

Comment: @etienne i want the column name of each row and store it in a seperate variable . also in a dynamic way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on etienne's comment, but will be inefficient for large dataset.

```
foo <- function(x){
  y <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  y <- paste0("x", y)
}
t(apply(dat, 1, foo))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,] "x9" "x8" "x7" "x6" "x10" "x5" "x4" "x2" "x1" "x3" 
# [2,] "x5" "x3" "x4" "x6" "x10" "x1" "x7" "x2" "x8" "x9"
```

Comment: instead of x1 to x10 i need to get values like - ab, cd ,as,df,fg,gh,hj,jk,kl,er,ef instead of x1 to x10  I need it in a dynamic way. means variable name is like ab,df....                         I need to get the exact column name instead of x1 x2 ...x10.

Comment: @JaikumarS: that is your second question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778751/how-to-replace-a-character-value-in-data-frame-in-using-function-in-r) right ?