# How to replace a character value in data frame in using function in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as

```
max1 max2 max3 max4 max5 max6 max7 max8 max9 max10
  x9   x8   x7   x6  x10   x5   x4   x2   x1    x3 
  x5   x3   x4   x6  x10   x1   x7   x2   x8    x9
```

My expected output should be:

```
max1 max2 max3 max4 max5 max6 max7 max8 max9 max10
abc   ab   cf   cd  zx   vb   qw   er   gh   fg 
 vb   fg   qw   cd  zx   gh   cf   er    ab  abc
```

it is huge data i want it like a function and using array.

Comment: So you have some kind of lookup vector that translates "x1" to "x10" with the relevant character replacements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create another `vector` ('lvls2') that is in the same order as the `unique` elements of 'df1' ('lvls'), then loop through the columns (`lapply(`), convert to `factor`, specify the `labels`, then reconvert back to `character`, and assign that to the original dataset.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.character(factor(x, 
                    levels=lvls, labels=lvls2)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(max1 = c("x9", "x5"), max2 = c("x8",
"x3"), max3 = c("x7", 
"x4"), max4 = c("x6", "x6"), max5 = c("x10", "x10"), 
max6 = c("x5", 
"x1"), max7 = c("x4", "x7"), max8 = c("x2", "x2"), 
max9 = c("x1", 
"x8"), max10 = c("x3", "x9")), .Names = c("max1", "max2", 
"max3", 
"max4", "max5", "max6", "max7", "max8", "max9", "max10"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


 lvls <- unique(unlist(df1))
 lvls2 <- c("abc", "vb", "ab", "fg", "cf", "qw", "cd",
              "zx", "gh", "er")
```

Comment: this will work for two observation alone . I have 1000 observation.

Comment: @JaikumarS You may need to create a lookup or `lvls2` vector to replace the elements.  Whether it is 2 or 1000 or 1 million, this should work if you provide the unique levels that are matching with the replacement vector.

Comment: all[] <- lapply(all, function(x) as.character(factor(x, levels=lvls, labels=lvls2)))
all <- structure(list(max1 = c(lvls2), max2 = c(lvls2), max3 = c(lvls2), max4 = c(lvls2), max5 = c(lvls2), max6 = c(lvls2), max7 = c(lvls2), max8 = c(lvls2), max9 = c(lvls2), max10 = c(lvls2)), .Names = c("max1", "max2", "max3", "max4", "max5", "max6", "max7", "max8", "max9", "max10"),  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
lvls <- unique(unlist(all))
lvls2 <- c("ab", "vb", "ab", "fg", "cf", "qw", "cd", "zx", "gh", "er",'as','ad','ae') I have used like this But throw error in that.

Comment: Error in factor(x, levels = lvls, labels = lvls2) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 13 should be 1 or 12

Comment: @JaikumarS There is some problem in the `length`  Please check the `str(lvls)` and `str(lvls2)`.  Both should be vector and have the same length.