# To find the nth maximum row in R with more than n variables and to give the variable name as the output?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 20 variables out of which I need to use 10 variables to find the first ,second, 3rd.....nth maximum .

The variables are `ab cd xy cf to ty re rt po lo....`

```
ab cd xy cf to ty re rt po  lo
 1  2  0  3  4  5  6  7  8   5
 2  1  5  4  6  4  2  1  0   3
```

My expected output should be:

```
max1 max2 max3 max4 max5 max6 max7 max8 max9 max10
  po  rt   re   ty  lo   to   cf   cd   ab    xy 
  to   xy  cf   ty  lo   ab   re   cd   rt    po
```

I have 100 observations.

This code is returing as X . But i need it as values

```
foo <- function(x){
  y <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  y <- paste0("x", y)
}
```

t(apply(dat, 1, foo))

Expected result is correct in the code above. I need the column name as ab cd xy cf to ty re rt po lo as the result values.

Comment: You already asked (almost) the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690973/how-to-find-the-second-third-and-nth-maximum-row-in-r-with-more-than-10-variabl) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778751/how-to-replace-a-character-value-in-data-frame-in-using-function-in-r) and both returned answers. Could you give us the `dput` of your data and explains what are the differences between your 3 questions ?

Comment: @etienne code which in the question is giving the value has x1 ,x2 ... but i need to value has character as ab cd xy cf to ty re rt po lo. that is not coming i am struglling to get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
newDF<-t(apply(df,1,function(x){colnames(df)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)]}))
newDF<-as.data.frame(newDF,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # convert the result in a dataframe and keep the values as strings, not as factors
colnames(newDF)<-paste0('max',1:ncol(df)) # put the column names

newDF
    max1 max2 max3 max4 max5 max6 max7 max8 max9 max10
1   po   rt   re   ty   lo   to   cf   cd   ab    xy
2   to   xy   cf   ty   lo   ab   re   cd   rt    po
```

DATA :

```
df<-structure(list(ab = 1:2, cd = c(2L, 1L), xy = c(0L, 5L), cf = 3:4, 
    to = c(4L, 6L), ty = c(5L, 4L), re = c(6L, 2L), rt = c(7L, 
    1L), po = c(8L, 0L), lo = c(5L, 3L)), .Names = c("ab", "cd", 
"xy", "cf", "to", "ty", "re", "rt", "po", "lo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

For your future questions, please provide `dput` : it allows us to have the same data as yours and is much more useful than just pasting the data.